# Adding the gzip.conf file to default.conf

Tags: nginx

In nginx how can I refer the gzip.conf to the default.conf, I have two files at the folder of

```
conf/conf.d
    default.conf
    gzip.conf
```

default.conf

```
server {
  listen 3000;
  location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    expires -1; # Set it to different value depending on your standard requirements
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
  location /health {
    return 200 'healthy\n';
  }
}
```

gzip.conf

```
gzip on;
gzip_http_version  1.0;
gzip_comp_level    5; # 1-9
gzip_min_length    256;
gzip_proxied       any;
gzip_vary          on;

# MIME-types
gzip_types
  application/atom+xml
  application/javascript
  application/json
  application/rss+xml
  application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  application/x-font-ttf
  application/x-web-app-manifest+json
  application/xhtml+xml
  application/xml
  font/opentype
  image/svg+xml
  image/x-icon
  text/css
  text/plain
  text/x-component;
```

How can I refer the gzip.conf file in default.conf?

Comment: There is no need to "refer" anything. The gzip will be applied to all sites. Or else, what are you trying to do?

Comment: So there is no need to refer it in default.conf isn't it will automatically take the file am i correct